# How can i identify wether a Markov Chain is irreducible?

Tags: markov-process

i am working on understanding Markov-Chains but i have a hard time understanding an irreducible MC. At our uni we have following definitions:

"If the set of all states is closed and does not contain any subset that is closed, then DTMC is irreducible
Alternative definition: A DTMC is irreducible if every state is reachable from any other state respectively communicates with every other state"

Actually, I have understood the definitions so far. But now we have the following question and answer in one of the tasks:

"An ergodic Markov chain has not more than 1
absorbing state?

Anwser: Ergodicity: Finite, irreducible, aperiodic Markov chain --> Statement: True".

As I understood it then, irreducible MC can have one absorbing state. But this would contradict my understanding of the definition of "irreducible", because all non-absorbing states can end up in an absorbing state, but an absorbing state cannot end up in the others. But this contradicts the definition. Why is the Markov chain A ergodic and therefore irreducible and the Markov chain B not?

[image]

Comment: Ergodicity means that the initial state does not impact the limiting behaviour of the chain. In case A, the limit is an atom at 4. In case B, starting from state 5 means ending up as an atom at 5, while starting from state 4 means ending up as an atom at 4.

Comment: @Xi'an thanks for your answer. That means 4 is ergodic but 5 isn't, correct? Does that mean ergodicity has nothing to do with an MC being irreducible?

Comment: I am afraid you 100% missed my point.